# Isotope + resize + imageLoaded

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

Hello to the helpers ones :) 
I've achieved to have a single wordpress page showing the images in a masonry fluid grid but I have a problem while calling a video in HTML5 (just with the tag: ). The problem is that the images work perfectly with width: 50%; height: auto; and the video loads to in the with but doesn't fit the masonry layout (it overlaps with other images) just when you resize the screen it fits in the grid. So I think I can solve it just with adding the .imageLoaded() plugin to the isotope call, but I can't figure it out when, my jQuery code is the following:

Really thanks for all in advance!

$(function(){

```
        var $container = $('#container'),
        // create a clone that will be used for measuring container width

            $containerProxy = $container.clone().empty().css({ visibility: 'hidden' });
        $checkboxes = $('#filters input');


        $container.after( $containerProxy );

        // get the first item to use for measuring columnWidth
        var $item = $container.find('.item').not('.w2').eq(0);

        $(window).smartresize( function() {
            // calculate columnWidth
            var colWidth = Math.floor( $containerProxy.width() / 4 );
            // set width of container based on columnWidth
            $container.css({
                width: colWidth * 4
            })
                .isotope({
                    // other options...
                    // disable automatic resizing when window is resized
                    resizable: false,
                    // set columnWidth option for masonry
                    masonry: {
                        columnWidth: colWidth
                    }
                });
            // trigger smartresize for first time
        }).smartresize();

        $checkboxes.change(function(){
            var filters = [];
            // get checked checkboxes values
            $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function(){
                filters.push( this.value );
            });
            // ['.red', '.blue'] -> '.red, .blue'
            filters = filters.join(', ');
            $container.isotope({ filter: filters });
        });



    });
```

Answer (score 0):

See the following code:

```
 $(function(){

    var $container = $('#container'),
    // create a clone that will be used for measuring container width

        $containerProxy = $container.clone().empty().css({ visibility: 'hidden' });
    $checkboxes = $('#filters input');


    $container.after( $containerProxy );

    // get the first item to use for measuring columnWidth
    var $item = $container.find('.item').not('.w2').eq(0);

    $(window).smartresize( function() {
        // calculate columnWidth
        var colWidth = Math.floor( $containerProxy.width() / 4 );
        // set width of container based on columnWidth

      $container.imagesLoaded( function(){  //Add Imagesloaded here


        $container.css({
            width: colWidth * 4
        })
            .isotope({
                // other options...
                // disable automatic resizing when window is resized
                resizable: false,
                // set columnWidth option for masonry
                masonry: {
                    columnWidth: colWidth
                }
            });
        // trigger smartresize for first time
    }).smartresize();

    $checkboxes.change(function(){
        var filters = [];
        // get checked checkboxes values
        $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function(){
            filters.push( this.value );
        });
        // ['.red', '.blue'] -> '.red, .blue'
        filters = filters.join(', ');
        $container.isotope({ filter: filters });
    });

     }); //imagesloaded end

   });
```

Comment: Don't really know why, but it breaks the masonry layout as well. :(

Comment: Are you loading the script  imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js before isotope?

Comment: Yes, I'm loading the imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js before isotope.